# Unit test on Angularjs with Jasmine and Webpack, error Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, webpack, jasmine

I would like to ask how to solve this error which won't let me write any test.
This is the Angularjs factory (service.es6) I would like to test:

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'
var TheMiddleModule = angular.module('TheMiddleModule', [])
TheMiddleModule.factory('TheMiddleOp', function ($http){
  var api = 'someUrl'
  var TheMiddleOp = {}

  TheMiddleOp.getSsoidFromService = () => {
     return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: api
        })
     )
   }

   return TheMiddleOp
})
```

This is my test webpack configuration:

```
var JasmineWebpackPlugin = require('jasmine-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  entry: ['./app/scripts/test/service.js'],
  plugins: [new JasmineWebpackPlugin()],
  output: {
      path: __dirname,
      filename: 'test.js'
  },
  module: {
      loaders: [
      {
          test: /\.es6$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          loader: 'babel?presets[]=es2015!eslint-loader'
      },
      {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          loader: 'babel?presets[]=es2015!eslint-loader'
      }
  ]
  }
 }
};
```

and this is my js test file:

```
import 'angular';
import 'angular-mocks';
import '../services/service.es6';

var service;

describe('service test', function() {
    var $httpBackend, $httpProvider;
    var module = angular.mock.module();
    var url = 'someUrl';

    beforeEach(function () {

        module('TheMiddleModule');

        inject(function ( _$httpBackend_, _TheMiddleOp_) {
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            service = _TheMiddleOp_;

            $httpBackend.when('POST', url)
            .respond(200, {'sso-id':'test'});
        });
    });

    it('$httpBackend should be defined', function (){
        expect($httpBackend).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('TheMiddleOp should be defined', function (){
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should call the ssoid service', function (){
        var getFromService = service.getSsoidFromService()
        getFromService.subscribe(
            (response) => {},
            (e) => {},
            () => {
                $httpBackend.expectGET(url);
                $httpBackend.flush();
            }
        )
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });
});
```

the error jasmine gives to me is:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: TheMiddleOpProvider <- TheMiddleOp
```

If I comment the row:

```
service = _TheMiddleOp_;
```

the $httpBackend test passes correctly and it fails the others, of course.
I also tried to import the service.es6 without any export, with only the module as a default export and with more combinations.
Thanks in advance for any help you could give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your module is not defined. Because the factory is registered to that module. So the error is in the module definition.

There could be three things wrong if I may guess:

```
var module = angular.mock.module();
```

Why is this needed? Why not write the angular.mock.module in the before each?

```
angular.mock.module('TheMiddleModule');
```

The other option is your factory and the choice of variables. My suggestion to rewrite it as followed:

```
angular.module('TheMiddleModule', [])
  .factory('TheMiddleOp', function ($http){
    var api = 'someUrl';

    return {
     getSsoidFromService = () => {
        return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(
          $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: api
        });
     )
    };
  });
```

The last option is that your webpack configuration is wrong. But you can debug your test you configure it not to be a singleRun;

Last comment, the unit test itself is not testing anything; And remove the check if $httpBackend is there because then your testing angular mock is working?

Comment: Thank you so much!
To solve this I have:
 (1)  wrote this angular.mock.module('TheMiddleModule'); as suggested
 (2)  rewrote the factory as suggested
 (3)  deleted the $httpBackend test.

After that the expect(service).toBeDefined(); passed the test and now I can finally work to write the actual tests.
Thanks again!